# post and get json in c restful webservice

Tags: c, json, rest, post

I read  tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html , i wonder how to post and get json from client with C or C++ without use jerson-client library.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 link for C ++ Restful

step 1:  add c++ rest sdk using NUGET (name: casablanca)

```
https://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20NuGet%20to%20add%20the%20C%2b%2b%20REST%20SDK%20to%20a%20VS%20project
```

step 2: Http Client Tutorial

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/603810/Using-Casablanca-to-consume-a-REST-API
```

before test this code you need to change host (http:......) that belongs to you

```
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace utility;                    // Common utilities like string conversions
using namespace web;                        // Common features like URIs.
using namespace web::http;                  // Common HTTP functionality
using namespace web::http::client;          // HTTP client features
using namespace concurrency::streams;       // Asynchronous streams
//==================GET and save in file abc.txt
auto fileStream = std::make_shared<ostream>();
// Open stream to output file.
pplx::task<void> requestTask = fstream::open_ostream(U("abc.txt")).then([=](ostream outFile)
{
    *fileStream = outFile;
    // Create http_client to send the request.
    http_client client(U("http://localhost:8080/JSonJersey/rest"));

    // Build request URI and start the request.
uri_builder builder(U("/getEmployee"));
//  builder.append_query(U("q"), U("Casablanca CodePlex"));c
return client.request(methods::GET, builder.to_string());
})
// Handle response headers arriving.
.then([=](http_response response)
{
 printf("Received response status code:%u\n", response.status_code());
// Write response body into the file.
return response.body().read_to_end(fileStream->streambuf());
})

// Close the file stream.
.then([=](size_t)
{
return fileStream->close();
});

// ================POST
pplx::task<int> Post()
{
return pplx::create_task([]
{
    json::value postData;
    postData[L"id"] = json::value::number(13);
    postData[L"firstName"] = json::value::string(L"Baseball");
    postData[L"lastName"] = json::value::string(L"hello");
    postData[L"age"] = json::value::number(32);
    http_client client(L"http://localhost:8080/JSonJersey/rest/class");
    return client.request(methods::POST, L"/PostJsonEmployee", postData.to_string().c_str(),     L"application/json");
}).then([](http_response response)
{
    printf("Received response status code:%u\n", response.status_code());
    return 0;
});
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

// Wait for all the outstanding I/O to complete and handle any exceptions
try
{

    requestTask.wait();
    Post().wait();
}
catch (const std::exception &e)
{
    printf("Error exception:%s\n", e.what());
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For C/C++ Development, You can use libcurl library for making http request. refer [here]. http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

For JSON, jsoncpp can be used.see here https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp